# Pasar los datos de una fila de una tabla a otra

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero tomar los datos de una fila seleccionada de una tabla y que me mande los datos a otra tabla, pero quiero que una columna no se mande a la segunda tabla. ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Este script lista los productos de una base de datos.

```
function listarVentas(){var nom = $("#caja").val();  
    $.get("CV",{"opc":1},function (data) {  
        
        var x = JSON.parse(data);  
        
          $("#tabla tbody tr").remove();     
        for(var i = 0;i<x.length;i++){  $("#tablaventas").append("<tr class='fila' ><td>"+(i+1)+"</td<td id='1'>"+x[i].idPro+"</td><td id='2'>"+x[i].nombre+"</td><td id='3'>"+x[i].precio+"</td><td>"+x[i].stock+"</td><td id='cantidad'><input name='' type='text'></td><td id='accion'><input name='' type='checkbox'></td></tr>");}  
    }); }
```

Esta es mi tabla en la cual se lista los productos (tabla1)

```
<table class="table" id="tablaventas" class="tblas" style="visibility: hidden"><thead>  
                    <tr>  
                        <th scope="col">#</th>  
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>  
                        <th scope="col">PRODUCTO</th>  
                        <th scope="col">PRECIO</th>  
                        <th scope="col">STOCK</th>  
                        <th scope="col">CANTIDAD</th>  
                        <th scope="col">ACCION</th>  
                    </tr>  
                </thead>  
                <tbody>                   
                </tbody>  
            </table>
```

Esta es la tabla en la cual quiero que la fila seleccionada de la tabla 1 envíe los datos, pero no quiero que envíe el dato de stock, sino que envíe el dato que
se ingresa en el input.
(tabla 2)

```
 <table class="table" id="tablaprodus"  >  
                <thead>  
                    <tr>  
                        <th scope="col">#</th>  
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>  
                        <th scope="col">PRODUCTO</th>  
                        <th scope="col">PRECIO</th>  
                        <th scope="col">CANTIDAD</th>  
                        <th scope="col">ACCION</th>  
                    </tr>  
                </thead>  
                <tbody>                   
                </tbody>  
            </table>
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida  SOes y te invito a que des un  vistazo  al [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Con referencia con tu pregunta trata de añadir mas información sobre tu problema como la estructura de tus dos tablas.

Answer (score 1):

Mira, realmente es muy simple :

```js
    (function($){
            $(function(){
                var trClone = $('#table1 tr:eq(1)').clone();
                trClone.find('td:eq(2)').remove();
                trClone.appendTo('#table2 tbody');
            });
        })(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>header1</th>
                <th>header2</th>
                <th>header3</th>
                <th>header4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data1</td>
                <td>data2</td>
                <td>data3</td>
                <td>data4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table id="table2" border="1">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>headerClone1</th>
                <th>headerClone2</th>
                <th>headerClone3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>clone1</td>
                <td>clone2</td>
                <td>clone3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Lo que se hace es clonar la tr que quieres, luego se remueve la columna con index x, y por ultimo se agrega esta tr clonada a la nueva tabla. la salida es:

[image: Captura del resultado]

Comment: Excelente aporte Nicolás!

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el enlace al ejercicio de como enviar datos de una tabla a otra y te explico brevemente como funciona:

En la primer tabla tengo datos fijos que son los que utilizare para enviar la fila a otra tabla

```
<table id="tabla1" border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Eviar" class="envio"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Eviar" class="envio"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Eviar" class="envio"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

La segunda tabla esta vacia:

```
<table id="tabla2" border="1" width="100%">
</table>
```

Dentro la la tabla1 hay un boton que servira para la interaccion con el usuario y asi podra pasar la fila a la tabla que esta vacia, para eso tenemos el siguiente codigo

```
$('.envio').on('click', function() {
    var hermano=$(this).parent();
    $("#tabla2").prepend("<tr>\
                                            <td>"+hermano.siblings("td:eq(0)").text()+"</td>\
                        <td>"+hermano.siblings("td:eq(1)").text()+"</td>\
                        <td>"+hermano.siblings("td:eq(2)").text()+"</td>\
                                        </tr>")
  });
```

Cuando se presione el boton lo que haremos sera regresar un nivel con la funcion parent() para ubicarnos al mismo nivel de los td, una vez ahí buscaremos a los hermanos de este td, por ejemplo A1,A2,A3 (para esto es la funcion siblings hermano.siblings("td:eq(1)")) con la opcion eq obtenemos cada uno de los elemento que queremos pasar a la tabla2 y obtenemos su texto con la funcion text().

Una vez que tenemos todos los datos la enviaremos a la tabla2 con la funcion $("#tabla2").prepend()

Te dejo el enlace para que veas como funciona
https://jsfiddle.net/e8geuoez/